# Bootstrap Angular dropdown menu not working in ChildRoute

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have admin bootstrap html and do manual integration with Angular where i put css file and JS file in angular.json like this

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "src/assets/googlefont.css",
          "src/assets/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "src/assets/vendors/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css",
          "src/assets/vendors/ladda/dist/ladda-themeless.min.css",
          "src/assets/vendors/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css",
  etc....
 
  "scripts": [
          "src/assets/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "src/assets/vendors/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js",
          "src/assets/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
          "src/assets/vendors/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.min.js",
etc....
```

in app.routing.module (Main Routes) i have structure :

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'front',
    component: FrontComponent,
  },

  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },

  {
    path: 'menu',
    loadChildren: () => import('./menu/menu.module').then(mod => mod.MenuModule)
  },

  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```

];

in menu.routing.module (Child Routes) i have structure :

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: MenuComponent,
  children: [
   {
     path: 'dashboard',
     component: DashboardComponent
   },
 
  ]
 }]
```

If I put html menu in MenuComponent (child routes) is not working properly, dropdown menu is not working and show hide left menu not working too.

```
  <li class="air__menuLeft__item air__menuLeft__submenu">
        <a href="javascript: void(0)" class="air__menuLeft__link">
          <i class="fe fe-hard-drive air__menuLeft__icon"></i>
          <span>Form Plugins</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="air__menuLeft__list">
          <li class="air__menuLeft__item">
            <a href="form-plugins-bootstrap-select.html" class="air__menuLeft__link">
              <span>Bootstrap Select</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="air__menuLeft__item">
            <a href="form-plugins-select2.html" class="air__menuLeft__link">
              <span>Select2</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="air__menuLeft__item">
            <a href="form-plugins-autocomplete.html" class="air__menuLeft__link">
              <span>Autocomplete</span>
            </a>
          </li>
 etc...
```

But if i put html on FrontComponent (Main Routes) is working properly. How to solve this problem

[image]

Comment: In Angular you **not** use "<a href='file.html'>" else "<a routerLink='/path'>", see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router). what are you try to do?

Comment: thank @Eliseo list menu <a href='file.html''> is not main problem, is only example html, the main problem is left menu is not working properly, i cannot click dropdown menu and show hide left menu properly

Answer (score 0):

After few days trial and error i have solution. I import manually my js external files (from angular.json) to menu.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// this files from angular.json js files external files (depend on your bootstrap js files)
import "../../assets/components/kit/core/index.js";
import "../../assets/components/airui/layout/menu-left/index.js";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listmenu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css'],
})

export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {
}
ngOnInit(): void { 
}
```

}

now is working properly